# WMS of Geoserver SQL view shows nothing, however WFS works properly

Tags: geoserver, wms, openlayers, sql-server

I am using Geoserver to create a WMS service to serve data out of an SQL Server database. Everything works fine (WMS & WFS) untill I create an SQLView in Geoserver.

The SQLView:

```
SELECT *
FROM rmaster
```

I have defined the CRS and geometry column. The WFS service of the SQLView works properly and serves the data, however the WMS serves empty images. Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: probably your style is broken

Comment: When I'm serving the original data (no sqlview) as wms, the style is working properly

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

There was a wrong row in the "spatial_ref_sys" table of the SQL Server database, which was referring to an unexisting SRS. I've replaced it with the following row for WGS84 SRS.

```
srid:4326   auth_name:EPSG auth_srid:4326   srtext:GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9108"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]  proj4text: +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```